# How do i ignore newline in .txt file in c

Tags: c

i am reading in from a text file and storing each element into a linked list. however when the program reaches a return char or newline the program returns an error.

reading from text file and storing into structs. I notice the error when i print each struct to the screen the program prints the last struct before the return char then quits.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    printf("Hello!\n");

    char filename[] = "artist.txt";

    print_artists(read_artists(filename));

    return 0;
}

    struct artist *read_artists(char *fname)
    {
        int maxlen = 225;

        int artid = 0;
        int altartid = 0;
        int pc = 0;
        char artname[80];

        char data[maxlen];
        int valid = 0; // 0 acts as true 1 acts as false
        int checkresult = 0; //checks result of sscanf

        struct artist *temphead = create_artist(0,0,0,"0");

        FILE *fp = fopen(fname ,"r");

        if (fp != NULL)
        {
            while (fgets(data,maxlen,fp))
            {
                checkresult = sscanf(data,"%d\t%[^\t\n]\n",&artid,artname);
                if (checkresult == 2)
                {
                    struct artist *b = NULL;
                    b = create_artist(artid,altartid,pc,artname);
                    temphead = add_artist(temphead,b);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("error checkresult = %d\n",checkresult);
                    printf("break out of loop valid = 1\n");
                    valid = 1; // acts as boolean variable
                    break; //breaks out of the while(fgets)
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
            return (temphead);
        }
        else
        {
            fclose(fp);
            printf("File Error\n");
            return (NULL);
        }

    }

void print_artists(struct artist *head)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        struct artist *temp = head;
        while (temp -> next != NULL)
        {
            print_artist(temp);
            temp = temp -> next;
        }
        print_artist(temp);
    }
}
```

this is the output

[image]

the text file i am reading from

[image]

Comment: Are you saying the program errors or that `printf("error checkresult = %d\n",checkresult);` is printed?

Comment: Note: best not to call `fclose(fp)` when `fp == NULL`.

Comment: program errors abort6 and i tried to debbug thats why I've addedprintf("error checkresult = %d\n",checkresult);

Comment: "I notice the error when i print each struct to the screen the program prints the last struct before the return char then quits." is unclear as posted code does not `printf()` `artid,altartid,pc,artname` anywhere.  I think the issue is in unposted code.

Comment: Show the first few lines of the text file you are reading from but not as an image but as text please, sigh.

Comment: There must be a linked list somewhere as the data is printed in reverse order of the file, and `create_artist()` is not shown, nor `#incude` files nor function prototypes. Are there any?

Comment: Suspect issue is with `create_artist()/add_artist()`.  2) With `print_artists()` I would expect `void print_artists(struct artist *head) { while (head) { print_artist(head); head = head->next; }}`

Comment: Side note: best to post true output (as text) with matching true code.  Since output is missing `"Hello!\n"` it lowers the confidence that code and output match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reach the blank line before Bodenstandig, the sscanf will not match and you will exit the while loop at the "break".

If sscanf does not return 2, you should check to see if the line is empty and if so skip and read the next line. Or just skip the check and ignore bad lines. The while(fgets(...) condition will become false at the end of the file, so you don't need to exit on a bad line.

```
if (checkresult == 2)
{
    ....
}
else
{
    continue; // will go back to top while(fgets(...))
}
```